# Why does default comparer consider null to be less than a value

Tags: c#, types, nullable

The docs for `Compare(T? x, T? y)` say:

> Returns:
> A signed integer that indicates the relative values of x and y
> Less than zero – x is less than y.
> Zero – x equals y.
> Greater than zero – x is greater than y.

Consider this example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Comparer<int?>.Default.Compare(null, 1)); // -1   ?huh?
        Console.WriteLine(Comparer<int?>.Default.Compare(-1, 1));   // -1
        Console.WriteLine(Comparer<int?>.Default.Compare(1, 1));    //  0
        Console.WriteLine(Comparer<int?>.Default.Compare(2, 1));    //  1
        
        Console.WriteLine((int?)null < 1);                          // False
        Console.WriteLine((int?)null == 1);                         // False
    }
}
```

So `null` is "less" than some value. I would have been less surprised if it returned a different magic number (e.g. `-2`), or thrown an exception, or whatever.

And `null < 1` is false, as expected, which seems counter to the above.

Is there some reason for this, or is it just an API quirk to be aware of?

Comment: The comparer, as far as I understand, always returns -1, 0, or 1. I wouldn't consider null to be the same or greater than in this case, so -1 makes most sense

Comment: Note that this is consistent with [`Nullable.Compare`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable.compare?view=net-5.0).

Comment: See also: https://ericlippert.com/2015/08/31/nullable-comparisons-are-weird/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It needs to have a defined comparison in terms of `IComparable<T>` / `IComparer<T>`, and it has *elected* that `null` is less than anything else. This is specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable.compare). The only other option would have been to throw an exception, which most people would consider a bad thing here, as it would break any sorting with nulls in.

The `<` operator is *entirely separate*, and has elected to return `false` when either operand is `null`. As non-intuitive as it seems: `CompareTo` and `<` do *not* need to agree precisely.

Comment: I thought maybe it was because nullable types were added to the language after those interfaces, so they shoehorned the logic in (no evidence for that, just a wild guess). But even so, your explanation makes more sense - it's just a design convention.

Answer (score 1):

This experiment will blow your mind (just like mine):

```
int? a = null;
int b = 0;
if (a < b)
    log.Debug("null is smaller than 0");
else if (a == b)
    log.Debug("null is equal to 0");
else
    log.Debug("null is larger than 0");
```

output : `null is larger than 0`
This does not mean that it is larger, it just means it is NOT smaller :-) )

But now, look at those values in the watch-window:

```
a     null   int?
b     0      int
a>b   false  bool
a<b   false  bool
a==b  false  bool
```

So, apparently, comparing `null` with an actual value gives bogus results.

Comment: Why is it that surprising? If we want to compare, say, the size of Australia with Unfoundia, a completely undefined entity, then none of the "bigger"/"smaller"/"equal" is valid.

Comment: According to the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell, I would expect `a>b` to be `true` when one of the two is `null`.

Comment: You can't really say something is "bigger" than something doesn't exist. Another analogy is comparing your birthdate to a person that doesn't exist. You weren't born after that person, since the non-existing person never existed, you also weren't born before, because that person also will never be born. Obviously, that person also doesn't share your birthdate.

Comment: @Dominique no, the c# spec  section 6.4.2 (lifted conversion operators) and 7.3.7 (lifted operators) defines the rules for using such operators with nullable types, and it is defined as returning false here

Comment: I do understand the situation. I just find it mind blowing that `a<b` yields `false`, while `a>b` also yields `false`.

Comment: @Dominique that (`a<b` and `a>b` both being `false`) would be entirely consistent with ANSI-standard database null rules, for example

Comment: Is Schrodinger's cat alive or dead? Yes. :-P They just chose one convention.

Comment: It's weird, but at least it's not javascript.